# Google Maps API v3 redraw editable and selectable shapes previously saved

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

I created an app with which shapes can be drawn on a map and they are editable and can be selected.

This was achieved by adding an "overlaycomplete" listener to the drawing manager and writing functions for setting the selected shape or clearing the selection or deleting the shape:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {

        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);

        var shape = e.overlay;
        shape.type = e.type;

        google.maps.event.addListener(shape, 'click', function() {
            select(shape);
          });
```

The details of all shapes can then be saved in a database. I now need to recreate the map with the same shapes which should be editable again. After loading the details from the database I have recreated the shapes but cannot seem to set a listener on them in order to use the same function as were used previously. The shapes are simply redrawn by specifying them so:

```
shape = new google.maps.Polygon({
                map: map,
                paths: paths,
                zIndex: 90,
                strokeWeight: 0,
                fillColor: color,
                fillOpacity: 0.65,
                editable: true
              });
```

After drawing the shapes this way, they are editable but I cannot select one shape at a time in order to, for example, delete it. ie. The shapes cannot be manipulated with the functions which were previously written.

Is there a way to set a listener?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for my problem. My saved shapes are being drawn by a loop and always have a variable name which gets incremented while the loop is running. While the loop is running I therefore set maps listeners on each of the shapes:

```
varString = "shape"+i;

    //Output shape
    window[varString] = new google.maps.Polygon({
                map: map,
                paths: paths,
                zIndex: 90,
                strokeWeight: 0,
                fillColor: color,
                fillOpacity: 0.65,
                myIndex: i,
                editable: true
              });

    google.maps.event.addListener(window[varString],"mouseout",function(){
                 path = this.getPath();
                 area = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(path);
                                     alert("area");
                });
```

Now I can set the same functions on each of the shapes and the user can edit them as before, the major difference being that a "select" function in now not possible and all shapes appear to be "selected" at a all times (the points on the corners which can be dragged are visible on all shapes, all the time).